# Reversing an array which is a value in object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, reverse

I am trying to reverse an array which is an element in an object.

```
colorKey = {
"2m":["#ffffff","#000000"]
}

colorKey["2mi"] = colorKey["2m"];
Array.reverse(colorKey["2mi"])
```

This is not working and returning colorKey["2mi"] the same as colorKey["2m"]. When I run the same command in developer console in browser, it reverses successfully. Where is the problem?

Comment: Array.reverse() I think return a new array with reversed elements, not modify the starting array

Comment: Try this: var reverse = Array.reverse(colorKey["2mi"]);

Comment: Are you sure it's `Array.reverse`? Because the only reverse function I found was `Array.prototype.reverse`.

Comment: `colorKey["2mi"] = colorKey["2m"]; console.log(colorKey["2m"]);
colorKey["2mi"] = colorKey["2mi"].reverse(); console.log(colorKey["2mi"]); `

Even this is not working. I am getting suspicious if this is something related to asynchronous timing of assignments. It works perfectly well in developer console.

Comment: Please re-read the documentation for the `reverse` method.

Comment: `Array.reverse` is a [generic method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Array_generic_methods) introduced in JavaScript 1.6. They are not part of ECMAScript standard, are deprecated, and will be removed. Don't use them.

Answer (score 0):

This is no static method off Array called `reverse`.  `reverse` is an instance method (`Array.prototype.reverse`) off the Array object, so the instance of the Array must be the caller.

This solves your problem:

```
colorKey = {
  "2m":["#ffffff","#000000"]
}

colorKey["2mi"] = colorKey["2m"];
colorKey["2mi"].reverse();
```

Output:
**["#000000", "#ffffff"]**

Comment: colorKey["2mi"] = colorKey["2m"]; console.log(colorKey["2m"]);
colorKey["2mi"].reverse(); console.log(colorKey["2mi"]);


This still gives 
["#000000", "#ffffff"]
["#000000", "#ffffff"]

Answer (score 0):

Calling reverse() for an array mutates it (reverse is in place - a new array is not created). What you want, apparently, is to have a reversed copy of the array. Basically, create a new array with the same values and then reverse it.

var a = [1, 2], b;
   b = a.slice(0).reverse();

Slice creates a new array with the same elements (but remember that it is not cloning the elements).

Answer (score 0):

@Rajat Aggarwal

**What you are asking for, is to clone your previous array in reverse order.**

The only trivial part of it would be reversing it. Because there is no way of cloning Objects and Arrays, nor a general method that you could write down as a function to be using it universally.

This specific array from the sample you provided can be cloned easily because it is flat and it only contains primitives. But the solution to it, will be exactly as specific as the sample array provided.

A specific solution to this task would be to use a plain coma-separated string of successive values and convert that to specific arrays of their corresponding primitive values.:

```
var colors = "#ffffff,#000000";
var colorKey = {
  "2m":colors.split(","),
  "2mi":colors.split(",").reverse() 
}
```

which will yield you a:

```
>> colorKey 
{
    2m : #ffffff,#000000,
    2mi : #000000,#ffffff
}
```